# Uppercase until end of group

Tags: captions, memoir, capitalization

In LaTeX, all font commands have two versions, one requires an argument (`\textbf`, `\textit`, `\textsc` etc), other changes the font until the end of group (`\bfseries`, `\itshape`, `\scshape` etc). The latter is especially useful when defining fonts for some auto-generated text in some package or class file. For example, with the memoir class:

```
\captionnamefont{\small\scshape}
```

or

```
\renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\Large\sffamily\bfseries}
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\sffamily\raggedright}
```

However, now I need a similar command for making text uppercase. `\MakeUppercase` requires an argument, but I don't know if there is a solution to make all text uppercase until end of a group, so that I could do something like:

```
\captionnamefont{\small\bfseries\lsstyle\MakeUppercaseUntilEndOfGroup}
```

In the event of no such command exists, to make this specific case work, I think I need to patch some internal memoir commands, something like this:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}[1]{\small\bfseries\lsstyle\lsstyle\MakeUppercase{\figurename~\thefigure}\quad}
\makeatother
```

However this is rather inelegant and limited; besides the fact that for other commands such as `\setsecheadstyle` this would have to be duplicated, even for floats, only captions for *figures* are changed. I also have tables and other custom float types defined by the `\newfloat` command. Then is it possible to simply define this new style for every kind of floats in my document? I suppose there is some code that creates new float types and maybe that should be patched...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you right you want to be able to use `\captionnamefont{\small\bfseries\lsstyle\MakeUppercase}` in order to change the appearance of all of `memoir`'s captions. One possibility of achieving this is to patch `\@makecaption` where the commands set with `\captionnamefont` are used.

`\captionnamefont` simply redefines `\@contnfont`. This command is now used in `\@makecaption` in five different places (due to some conditionals) in the following way: `\@contnfont #1\@contdelim`.

The example below changes all these appearances into `\@contnfont{#1\@contdelim}` so that the last command in `\captionnamefont` may have an argument:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd[\long]{\@makecaption}
  {\@contnfont #1\@contdelim}
  {\@contnfont{#1\@contdelim}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd[\long]{\@makecaption}
  {\@contnfont #1\@contdelim}
  {\@contnfont{#1\@contdelim}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd[\long]{\@makecaption}
  {\@contnfont #1\@contdelim}
  {\@contnfont{#1\@contdelim}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd[\long]{\@makecaption}
  {\@contnfont #1\@contdelim}
  {\@contnfont{#1\@contdelim}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd[\long]{\@makecaption}
  {\@contnfont #1\@contdelim}
  {\@contnfont{#1\@contdelim}}
  {}{}
\makeatother
\captionnamefont{\small\bfseries\lsstyle\MakeUppercase}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
 \caption{test caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I have come up with a semi-elegant answer for my own problem, but I'm still waiting for better answers.

Instead of the suggested way to patch the memoir code that creates new float types, I have come up with a macro that patches each float type individually. But at least there is a central way to specify the style of all float captions:

```
\makeatletter
\def\redeffloatcapstyle#1{%
  \expandafter\renewcommand\expandafter{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}[1]{%
    \small\bfseries\lsstyle\MakeUppercase{%
      \expandafter{\csname #1name\endcsname}~\expandafter{\csname the#1\endcsname}\quad
    }
  }
}
\makeatother
\redeffloatcapstyle{figure}
\redeffloatcapstyle{table}
% add your own new float types here; you might have to first define \newfloattypename, like this:
\def\codelistingname{Code Listing}
\newfloat{codelisting}{lcd}{\codelistingname}
\newcommand{\cdref}[1]{\codelistingname~\ref{#1}}
\redeffloatcapstyle{codelisting}
```

With this macro, saying `\redeffloatcapstyle{whatever}` is equivalent to saying:

```
\renewcommand{\fnum@whatever}[1]{\small\bfseries\lsstyle\MakeUppercase{\whatevername~\thewhatever}\quad}
```

This is kinda helpful, but still not as elegant if we could just patch the memoir code that defines new float types. So, still waiting for an answer...

Comment: I think it's a good way to patch the command.

Answer (score 4):

Non-LaTeX-y, and perhaps a bit roundabout way for use with XeTeX would be to make a mapping file along the lines of:

```
; caps.map
LHSName "Caps"
RHSName "UNICODE"
pass(unicode)
U+0061 > U+0041
U+0062 > U+0042
U+0063 > U+0043
; ...
U+007A > U+005A
```

(compile with `teckit_compile caps.map`)

and when loading the font, make use of the mapping:

```
\font\caps="Latin Modern Roman:mapping=caps"
```

and then you could do

```
{\caps All of this would be in caps}
```

Comment: I see what you mean. But limiting the engine to XeTeX is a bit restricting, and apparently it doesn't have microtype support (which is quite important as it is better to letterspace uppercase letters).

Comment: @kccqzy: I've used `letterspace=x` in the font loading options, where `x` is the font size. I know it's not as good as coming up with good values for each individual kerning pair, but still.

Comment: I marked the other answer as accepted because it solves the specific problem better. Your answer is indeed a bit roundabout but  is more general. Apparently I could not set two answers as accepted but I upvoted yours. Sorry if that bothers you.

Comment: @kccqzy: heh, no, it doesn't bother me. I'm glad you got answer that helped you `:-)`